# Call Server Side function/event using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

How to call a server side function/event using jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) jQuery methods. You can use these to either send a GET or POST request to the server, and the server can process whatever needs to be done server-side and return the results to jQuery. I suggest looking through the jQuery API page I linked to get a better understanding of how AJAX works within jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

To call a server side functionality. You need to understand the concept of Ajax. jquery also provides some of the methods which can be used to make ajax hits.